# How to assign values (new or existing column) to equivalent of xs with pandas MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a MultiIndex DataFrame `dfA`:

```
          0  1
i ii iii      
A C  D    1  2
     E    3  4
B C  D    5  6
     E    7  8
```

I want to add columns from another DataFrame, `dfB`,which matches the MultiIndex of `dfA` on all levels except one:

```
      2  3
i ii      
A C   1  2
B C   5  6
```

I was able to do so using,

```
dfA.loc[idx[:,:,'E'],dfB.columns] = dfB
```

Yielding,

```
          0  1    2    3
i ii iii                
A C  D    1  2  NaN  NaN
     E    3  4  1.0  2.0
B C  D    5  6  NaN  NaN
     E    7  8  5.0  6.0
```

However, this doesn't work if the MultiIndex only has 2 levels or when I tried a DataFrame that matches on the last levels instead of the first levels.

Is there a better way to do this? Or one that works more consistently (i.e. independent of where the extra level is)? I also want to be able to set the `NaN` elements afterwards, e.g. using

```
dfA.loc[idx[:,:,'D'],dfB.columns] = dfB*2
```

which I was unable to figure out how to merge with existing columns using `merge` or `join`, and `combine_first` doesn't have an option to operate on a subset of the DataFrame as far as I am aware...

Comment: Kindly share the dataframe as a dict `df.to_dict('records')`

Answer (score 0):

You could use pd.merge for that:

```
dfC = pd.merge(dfA, dfB, how="outer", left_index=True, right_index=True)
```